# Is my schema.org breadcrumb setup correctly?

Tags: xhtml, breadcrumbs, schema.org

I don't know if i set my breadcrumbs correctly, all my pages have breadcrumb like so:

```
<body itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

<div class="breadcrumb">
<a title="MY Site Title" rel="home" itemprop="breadcrumb" href="http://www.mysite.com/">MY Site Title</a>
<span class="navigation-pipe">»</span>
<a title="Category Name" itemprop="breadcrumb" href="http://www.mysite.com/CategoryName">Category Name</a>
<span class="navigation-pipe">»</span>Product Page
</div>
```

And if its a Product page i add this to the body after the breadcrumb.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

With Product info HERE

</div>
```

Comment: See WebSchemas/Breadcrumbs http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Breadcrumbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding

```
    itemprop="breadcrumb"
```

to the containing div, not the links themselves.  [As shown in the correct answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371410/adding-microdata-or-schema-org-for-breadcrumb-seo-in-drupal-7).

You can also use Google's own [structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&html=) to test what data it is able to extract.

They also have a [troubleshooting section](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1093493) which describes common pitfalls.

Finally, if all else fails [you can ask them manually](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/request.py?&contact_type=rich_snippets_feedback) though they don't promise an individual response.