# Google Rich Snippet Test Tool validate breadcrumb but real google result dont show it

Tags: documentation, breadcrumbs, microdata, rich-snippets

As defined by https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en I was using the following:

```
<title>mybiz | prd01 partnumber</title>
<!-- a lot of markup here -->
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/breadcrumb/collection">
    <div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a href="http://www.mybiz.com.jr/cat-prod01/" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">cat-prod01</span>
        </a> 
    </div>
    <div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <span>›</span>
        <a href="http://www.mybiz.com.jr/prod01/" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">prod01</span>
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

on the Google Rich Snippet Test Tool it works ok, the fragment and on the hole page, the
result is here http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004ead5f1f7ed7df2ea229e48ac0492

but the real Google result dont show the rich snippet, there is someone complaining about 
problems here [Breadcrumb with Schema.org not showing in Google Rich Snippets testing tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088284/breadcrumb-with-schema-org) and here [schema.org Breadcrumb Navigation is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773507/schema-org-breadcrumb-navigation-is-not-working)

There is people telling its not ready but schema.org dont warn about it.

others pages on the web that i searched get it working and i will change to something like it :

```
<title>mybiz | prd01 partnumber</title>
<!-- a lot of markup here -->
<div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" id="BreadCrumbs">
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">&nbsp;
        <a href="http://www.c.jr/mybiz" rel="v:url" property="v:title">mybiz</a>
    </span>
    &nbsp;›&nbsp;          
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a href="http://www.c.jr/catprd01" rel="v:url" property="v:title">cat-prod01</a>
    </span>
    &nbsp;›&nbsp;
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a href="http://www.c.jr/catprd01/prd01" rel="v:url" property="v:title">prod01</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

is possible see its working **TOO** here http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004ead6128f340ee942649a82819d22

but im afraid that it dont work **TOO**.

someone can help me, what can i do when i follow the docs and the test tool tell its ok but the real one not ?

Now when the change is done its dont work anymore when on the hole page but fragment works, waiting for the effect on the real Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never tell Google how to act, you can only request. With this I mean that you can never be sure if Google will show your markup for rich snippets. If it validates, then it's correct.

A suggestion is, as mentioned in the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373534/570796, to use Googles data vocabulary: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en&topic=1088474&ctx=topic
This has been known to be more accepted for some reason. But again, you can only mark it up and request for it to be shown..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort, i losted a lot doing it and expected Google be more sensible to it to be kind here. I will try your suggestion.